# What is an equivalent of MooseX::NonMoose for Moo?

Tags: perl, oop

I would like to use Moo instead of Moose, but I also need to inherit from non-Moose classes. How should I deal with that? Is there a module to work around this? If not, is there a way I can handle it myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moo can handle subclassing non-Moo/Moose classes already. You don't need an extension.

See the documentation for [FOREIGNBUILDARGS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo#FOREIGNBUILDARGS), which states:

> If you are inheriting from a non-Moo class, the arguments passed to the parent class constructor can be manipulated by defining a FOREIGNBUILDARGS method. It will receive the same arguments as BUILDARGS, and should return a list of arguments to pass to the parent class constructor.

Comment: If the parent class isn't hash based, you might need  [MooX::InsideOut](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooX::InsideOut)